# my laptop/Dock station does not detect the third extra screen

Tags: windows-7, laptop, multiple-monitors, graphics-card, hdmi

I have a Lenovo T430 and it is attached to a docking station. I was already using it with one monitor(HDMI) and extending it to the laptop screen it self.

Now, following are the slots that I can see on the docking station

1 X VGA
2 X Digital
1 X HDMI (already in use)

I though to order more screens that I can have total 4 monitors. I order 2 extra screens and attached them to Digital port.

Now, It extends to the new two attached screens but somehow it does not even see the already attached HDMi screen. it seems like it is disabled.

I have 3 screens now 2 Digital + monitor itself.

I am not sure if there is any way to even know if my computer does not support 3 extra screens. If it is not going to support 4 monitors(1 laptop itslef + 2 Digital + 1 HDMI) then I at least need the laptop monitor disabled which is small in comparison to extra screens.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which docking station model do you have?

Comment: Its Lenovo ThinkPad MiniDock series with Usb 3.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Lenovo documentation, 3 monitors can be connected simultaneously if you are using the dedicated GPU in the laptop.  If you are using the Integrated GPU only two monitors will work.

I'm familiar with the T430 and I know it's fairly common to disable the dedicated GPU in the BIOS to extend the battery life.  Check the BIOS and NVidia settings to make sure Optimus is enabled and turned on.

From Lenovo website:
"Up to three, of the five, video ports can be used simultaneously:

ThinkPad systems with NVIDIA Optimus technology: Up to three monitors can be attached."

[Product spec page](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/product-and-parts/detail.page?LegacyDocID=MIGR-76767)